# jquery help to get element in array that contains certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    jqTds =[
<td class=​"hidden-xs  sorting_1">​text1​</td>​
<td class="​ ">​text2​</td>​
<td class=​" ">​text3​</td>​
<td class=​" ">​text4​</td>​
<td class=​" ">​<a href=​"#" class=​"edit-row">​Edit​</a>​</td>​
<td class=​" ">​<a href=​"#" class=​"delete-row">​Delete​</a>​</td>​]
```

How can I get all elements that has a "anchor" with class "edit-row" or "delete-row" and get all other that does not have it

// I am editing a script that uses DataTables.Js what I am trying to do is getting all  elements from a table row into (var jqTds = $('>td:not(.hide_me)', nRow)) and now I want to include an input in all elements except the ones that has save-row class and edit-row class cos they are link to save/delete

thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, all <td> are in the array

Comment: Can you explain why and how you get them into an array in the first place? The code shown is invalid (and confusing) :)

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you have them in "an array", but if you run this while they are still in the DOM, use the `:has` pseudo selector:

```
var $tds = $('td:has(a:.edit-row,a:delete-row)');
var $otherTds = $('td').not($tds);
```

The first one reads. *find any td that *has* an anchor within it with class `edit-row` *or* an anchor within it with class `delete-row`".

The second one simply says, find all `td`s and exclude the first lot from the matches :)

Comment: Thanks TruBlueAussie, but how do I search it o array (jqTds) ?

Comment: @Fernando.M: Can you explain why and how you get them into an array in the first place? The code shown is invalid (and confusing) :)

Comment: // I am editing a script that uses DataTables.Js what I am trying to do is getting all <td> elements from a table row into (var jqTds = $('>td:not(.hide_me)', nRow)) and now I want to include an input in all elements except the ones that has save-row class and edit-row class cos they are link to save/delete

Comment: @Fernando.M: That is not an array... that is a jQuery object (which also happens to be an array behind the scenes). The above example would work with what you show. You need to show all the relevant code in context to get a concise  answer (before it gets closed) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) to filter your array.

Using the function passed to `$.grep()` you can try and find your elements within the current `<td>`. If neither `a.edit-row` or `a.delete-row` are found return true, otherwise return false:

```
var filteredTds = $.grep(jqTds, function(td){
    var $td = $(td);
    return !$td.find('a.edit-row').length && !$td.find('a.delete-row').length;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9hw4yvj/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do like this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < editColumn.length; i++) {

            if ($(editColumn[i]).find("a").hasClass("edit-row") == true) {

                editColumn[i].innerHTML = '<a class="save-row" href="">Salvar</a>';

            }
            else if ($(editColumn[i]).find("a").hasClass("delete-row") == true) {

                editColumn[i].innerHTML = '<a class="cancel-row" href="">cancelar</a>';
            }
```